# Why SWT system color is disposed?

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

I use the follow code

```
Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE)
```

to get the color for setting background of a label. It seems work fine for Windows system but on Mac system, it returns a color already disposed and hence, eventually it gives

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
```

What should be the explanation for it and how should I do it more properly?

Comment: Never seen this on my Mac. Where are you getting 'argument not valid'? I think you need to show us a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: had a similar issue and in my case it was caused by calling dispose() on Color instances returned by the getSystemColor() fn -which is wrong-